# Privilege highlighting flips back and forth without moving mouse

Tags: bug, status-completed, google-chrome, privileges-page

I want to report a bug on the [privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) on Stack Overflow.

The bug only occurs on Chrome.  Below are steps to reproduce:

1. Access to the [privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)
2. Hover mouse to right middle of lines as the following image

   > [image: screenshot]
3. I saw that the `trusted user` line gets highlighted, and without moving the mouse the `protect questions` line was highlighted, and it continued flipping back and forth until I moved my mouse.

This occurs on the latest Chrome under Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12, not on Firefox or IE. And there's the same error for the page on this site.

**Note**: to easier to reproduce, please use an external mouse to move exactly to right middle of two lines.

Comment: So you mean the highlight changes back and forth without you moving your mouse?

Comment: Yeah, not sure what you mean. Can you be more specific of the actual issue? As the lines being highlighted from hovering over them is correct behaviour.

Comment: @psubsee2003 yes! (I'm sorry for my bad English)

Comment: @TuanDang I'd suggest also providing the exact version # of Chrome that does this.  "Latest" version is almost meaningless, especially for browsers that upgrade as much as Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Thats what its supposed to do; presumably microscopic movements of your mouse are causing it go change selection

Comment: (Doesn't happen if you actually have those privileges; was able to repro on a site where I don't.)

Comment: @psubsee2003 on Windows 7, it's `Version 30.0.1599.101 m`

Comment: This happens to me as well, Chrome 30.0.1599.69 m. It happens even if I do not have my hand on the mouse.

Comment: @RichardTingle: considering it doesn't happen on the edge between any other items that get highlighted on mouseover, I'd say it's probably not supposed to do it.

Comment: @Wooble It occurs on privileges that I have not earned yet

Comment: This looks more like a bug with Chrome. The hover effect is done by pretty standard CSS, and it definitely shouldn't be doing that, but there's not really anything Stack Exchange can do to fix it. There's no overlapping and it doesn't change the height, so there's absolutely no reason Chrome should be doing that.

Comment: @animuson I tested the fix and it seems to solve the problem without causing any other issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually for programming issues you can find your questions [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11812447/814064) on Stack Overflow.

Here's the current CSS:

```
.privilege-table-row.earned {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

If you add `position: relative` to the CSS the issue is resolved.

```
.privilege-table-row.earned {
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to apply this bug fix on Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 2):

The issue has been fixed as suggested by [dcaswell](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202038/131112). Kudos.

The patch is in, waiting to be deployed in the next build.

Comment: I've already checked and the issue was fixed :D.